# POST serialized JSON object to a Coldfusion remote method instead of using FORM

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, coldfusion

I have javascript object which consists of complex array of structures with nested structures of other javascript objects created dynamicaly on page etc. long story. I can't use form since my vars would be like 2_34_x_y_foo_bar_235423 due to the nature of UI.

When I send that stringified object using GET .ajax request to a remote cfc method everything runs ok until JSON becomes 4000+ chars long, and usually it will be longer then that.

When I use POST .ajax, I get 302 status and redirection to cfcexplorer.

**Is there some way I could "attach" object to a form and send my data as form submit,
or some way to send JSON object as it is now using ajax call?**

Comment: How are you doing the "POST" - are you simply sending the stringified JSON data, or are you doing something like `jsondata=...`?
Most "standard" web apps would probably not like a POST with a single string rather than a "formfield=value" style posting, due to their parsing mechanisms (unless you've handrolled your own...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When posting to a remote CFC method, you have to make sure you still have your "method=cfcMethodName" as part of the request.

You can keep that in the URL part (POST /mycfc.cfc?method=myMethodName), or you can add it as a form field in the post.

The redirect is CF not getting a method to run, and therefore thinking you're trying to introspect the CFC.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much what I'm doing in a current project:

```
form = $("<form method='POST' action='/foo'><input type='hidden' name='data'></form>")
form.find("input").val(JSON.stringify(my_data_object));
form.hide().appendTo($("body")).submit();
```

(Note that I have no experience with Coldfusion whatsoever; this is a Python project.)

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same, somehow didn't work at once so I gave up thinking it can't be done like that. Good tip.